# Java Timer Program - rubix cube

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I am trying to make a rubix cube timer for my friend.  To start the timer you hold down space bar, and once you let go it starts.  I am having a problem though, when I hold down the space bar the timer starts at whatever time it is.  I want to be able to reset it to 0 but whenever I try to do that everything glitches out.  Could anyone tell me how to fix it, or how to do this in a more efficient way? Thanks!

```
package dev.suns.rubix_timer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class RubixTimerMain extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JLabel labelTimer;
private Timer timer;

public RubixTimerMain() {
    createWindow();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RubixTimerMain();
}

private void createWindow() {

    // setUndecorated(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    contentPane = new JPanel();

    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(201, 77, 83));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                startTimer();
            }
        }
    });

    JLabel lblMinimize = new JLabel("-");
    lblMinimize.setBounds(1835, -20, 16, 95);
    lblMinimize.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            lblMinimize.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            lblMinimize.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
    lblMinimize.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lblMinimize.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    contentPane.add(lblMinimize);

    JLabel lblX = new JLabel("X");
    lblX.setBounds(1873, 0, 24, 54);
    lblX.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            lblX.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            lblX.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });

    lblX.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    lblX.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblX.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.add(lblX);

    labelTimer = new JLabel("0.0.0");
    labelTimer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelTimer.setFont(new Font("DINPro-Bold", Font.PLAIN, 200));
    labelTimer.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    labelTimer.setBounds(371, 134, 1418, 653);
    contentPane.add(labelTimer);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

This is where I have the timer code.  I have tried to reset cal to 0 in several different places but it is not working.

```
private void startTimer() {
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
            Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            int milliseconds = cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
            labelTimer.setText(minutes + "." + seconds + "." + milliseconds);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

Comment: off topic: That kind of puzzle is called Rubik's Cube instead of Rubix Cube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to stop the timer thread you need to have some means of communicating between the main thread and the timer thread. A synchronized member variable of the RubixTimerMain class can do that:

```
private Boolean isStopped = new Boolean(true);
```

Then you can add two methods. One stops the timer by setting the variable, the other one checks the current state of the variable.

```
private void stopTimer(){
    synchronized(isStopped){
        isStopped = true;
    }
}

private boolean isTimerRunning(){
    boolean result = false;
    synchronized(isStopped){
        result = !isStopped;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You will want to change the listener event of the space key (in createWindow) like this so that it starts and stops the timing:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            if (isTimerRunning()){
                stopTimer();
            } else {
                startTimer();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Finally you need to adapt your thread function so that it only runs if the stopped state variable is false. Notice that it uses the isTimerRunning method instead of directly accessing the variable. Also the error of displaying the wrong time is fixed by converting the value of the GregorianCalendar into milliseconds first, then subtracting the recorded start time from the current time.

```
private void startTimer() {
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            long timeStart = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();
            synchronized(isStopped){
                isStopped = false;
            }

            while(isTimerRunning())
            {
                long timeNow = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() - timeStart;
                long milliseconds = (timeNow % 1000);
                timeNow = (long) Math.floor(timeNow * 0.001f);
                long seconds = (timeNow % 60);
                timeNow = (long)Math.floor((float)timeNow / 60f);
                long minutes = timeNow;

                labelTimer.setText(minutes + "." + seconds + "." + milliseconds);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: One biggest problem of your code is that you have chosen the wrong target to synchronize.  In this case it may not be fatal but if you keep using such practice you will eventually be having big trouble.  Simply marking the method as `synchronized` is good enough

Comment: For the problem of synchronzing with `isStopped`, think this case: `isStopped = false`; thread 1 locked `isStopped`; thread 2 come and wait; then thread 1 changed `isStopped` to `true`, then release lock; thread 2 get the lock of "false", then thread 3 come and `isStopped` is now true, thread 3 will be able to get the lock of `true`.  At this point, thread 2 and 3 are running at the same time while they are supposed to be synchronized.

Comment: @AdrianShum: sorry, but I think you get it wrong. The value of isStopped is completely irrelevant for the synchronized statement. Especially multiple threads will never see multiple different states of that variable - there is only one distinct value at any time. 
See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html
In the above link you can even see that they use synchronized(this) which could never work if multiple (waiting) threads would get/see different states of "this".

Comment: As for synchronizing the whole method: I deliberately did not do that, because synchronizing the whole method lets other threads wait at the very call of that method. Instead when only the parts are locked that actually need synchronization (here: access to isStopped) then the waiting time is minimized. Ok, admitted: the two little method in this example are trivial so there is quite little difference between synchronizing the method or the variable. But in general synchronizing whole methods in which only a little part actually needs locking hurts performance of multithreaded programs.

Comment: you didn't get what I was trying to say. What you did is a typical example of premature optimisation, and even worse, it is done wrong in many aspects. First synchronize(this) is correct in this example actually, but synchronizing on a Boolean variable is not. Follow closely on what I said before and you will see an example that such style will lead to case that not synchronizing. Moreover, you thought you are reducing contention but unfortunately you are doing the opposite. Remember the two values of Boolean is actually a flyweight in Java. Which means, if you use such style and

Comment: You have different classes etc doing similar thing by synchronizing on the Boolean, all of them are actually synchronizing on the same 2 instances and turned out you are creating more contention.

Answer (score 0):

One problem may be that you're not interacting with `labelTimer` on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).

In Swing, all interactions with UI objects must happen on this thread.

What happens if you make sure your call to `setText` happens within an invocation of `SwingUtilities#invokeLater`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)